# Is there a an Android app. for joining several photographs into a larger flat image?

Tags: panorama, android

I want to take some large photographs of objects on the floor by taking several images and stitching them together.

I've tried out some panorama apps. but while they automatically stitch the images nicely, they "bend" them to the usual panorama projection.

Are there apps. which can automatically stitch into a large flat picture? What's the name of this type of software?

Comment: This question might be better suited to [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) and [this](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/why-is-there-so-much-hostility-to-what-should-i-buy-and-shopping-questions) about "shopping" questions. They simply aren't a good fit on SE in general.

Answer (score 3):

Most such apps I've found for Android are fairly poor in quality.  The best I've found so far is [**Bimostitch**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.rethinkvision.Bimostitch&hl=en).

It has a bunch of settings and I believe you can change the projection mode (ie, from spherical to cylindrical to a flat projection).

Note: the panorama features in the camera app on recent Samsung devices is pretty good too, though it only works in one direction (it can't do multi-row).

Comment: This just locks up my phone's CPU and never finishes 

Comment: Depending on the settings, it can take a legit long time - eg 20 minutes on some settings